# What happens if I replace the underlying sqlite database when a SQLiteOpenHelper has opened the database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

What happens if I replace the underlying sqlite database when a SQLiteOpenHelper has opened the database? I suppose somehow the helper is operating on a file-descriptor. Can it break if I replace the sqlite file underneath?

I have taken read/write locks around e.g. query(), update() etc, and when I replace the file underneath it seems to work without issues. However I don't know how safe this is. Is it mandatory to also close the SQLiteOpenHelper before read or write manipulation of the underlying file? I am only accessing the database through a ContentProvider, so as far as I know it shouldn't be accessed elsewhere. Except also from my shell commands.

I am using the built in .restore and .backup commands to backup/replace the database via shell commands in code.

I am trying to achieve seamless backup and restore of the database.

Comment: quite an interesting question, i wonder if it would even be possible to replace the file while another process is busy with it, but if you're already doing this then i guess it's possible

Comment: Well, maybe sqlite immediately closes the file while having received and processed one request? Not sure how it works.

Comment: yeah, i do find it a bit suspicious that it would be possible to replace one file while another process is using it, you could have been fortunate so far and your operations have completed before you override the file, but i really don't know enough about this, hoping you find an answer